# Using Map-Reduce directly in python language?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

Can we use a python code in Map-Reduce instead of using Javascript?

In MongoDB they changed the Jaavascript engine to V8, this will make the operation parallelized, but frear about NoSql Injection since there is javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB map and reduce functions must be written in JavaScript.

Unless you are using input from the end-user, I'm not sure how you are worried about NoSQL code being injected into your mapReduce functions.

Comment: there are a lot  of nosql attacks, they use it by injecting javascript code

Comment: "they" can only do it if you are using user input data (unvalidated) in your map-reduce code generation. "injection" can't "just" happen because you use mapreduce - the malicious JS has to somehow be allowed into your process!

Comment: but i dont understand here, since it  is javascript, than system has allowed it no?

Comment: did you actually read it?  the only time there can be an injection is if you include ENDUSER INPUT in your javascript code.

Comment: sorry if i dont understand, but every operation in an application will wait for an end user input? i dont follow you?

Comment: when you run mapreduce you have to provide it the source code for map and reduce functions. Injection of malicious code into it is not possible if YOU are providing this code (injection is only possible if you are getting some enduser input in your application and putting that into the mapreduce source without cleansing it).

Comment: ah, now i got the idea :) 
so now with V8 it must be more powerful than aggregation framework?

Comment: no, aggregation framework will still be faster because it runs on the server, mapreduce has to spawn a separate javascript thread. V8 is faster than Spidermonkey but aggregation framework is faster than either of them (and it's faster in 2.4 than it was in 2.2).

Comment: ahhhh now i get clear ideas that i can organize, why i ask those question is because my graduation project i used mongodb, so i must speak about map reduce because the project will talk about nosql, and as case study: mongodb! 
last question (sorry) so then aggregation framwork, no need to use Hadoop since they'll do the same job, or Hadoop will be better on very large amount of data?

Comment: depends on the amount of data and the type of computations. MongoDB mapreduce only works on one MongoDB collection (at a time) - Hadoop can analyze data from multiple different sources.